# React: How to concatenate string with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to take a server response which contains HTML and replace parts of it with React components. The html from the server looks something like this:

```
<div><h1>Title</h1>[video] [image]</div>
```

I would like to replace [video] and [image] with React components which display a video player and an image. In reality the components are a little more complex but this should show a simple example.

I've set up a code pen but so far have only been able to get this output as I'm combining React components with strings.

```
Title
[object Object] [object Object]
```

https://codepen.io/adamoliver/pen/pRYXeB

Any ideas on what a potential solution might be for this?

Comment: Maybe your approach is not the best, JSX components are in fact javascript, so you won't be able to concatenate them with a string. But if what you want is to **take a response** from the server with JSX components you should take a look to **react server side rendering**. Particularly to `renderToString`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use something like https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone to compile the JSX on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Since someone hsa suggested, you should check out https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring

I think the right way to handle this case is to convert a piece of string into an JSX element, which in internally objects returned from `React.createElement()`, described at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this as a function call instead of component.
Find this codepen.

> ```
> `https://codepen.io/satya-dash/pen/QdPwep`
> ```